# Create files on fly based on the Day in the contents

Tags: php, shell

I have some data in file which contains Day in one of the lines. Based on the day, I want to copy the data into specific directory. How can i do this in PHP or Shell Script?

file1.txt:

```
101
RJ
Printer
Monday
```

file2.txt:

```
101
RJ
Switch
Wednesday
```

I would like to copy first data into a directory "Monday" and other one "Wednesday". Any suggestions in either PHP or Shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point here is how you detect "the day".
Presuming that "day"-line contains "day" at the end of the string:

```
for i in file*.txt
do
  day=$(cat $i| grep day$ | head -1)
  [ -z "$day" ] && day=UNKNOWN
  mkdir -p "$day"
  cp "$1" "$day"
done
```

In the case:

- when there are two ore more "days" in file, will be used the first one
- when there are no "day" in file, file will be copied to `UNKNOWN` directory

Comment: Presuming `Michael Faraday` does not show up in those files :P

Comment: This works however as expected. However, I am getting few days where I have prefixes like "2 x Monday" or "4 x Tuesday". In this case this program is creating directory like 2 x Monday or 4 x Tuesday. I don't want to create any new directories. I have created all the directories with days and would like to just copies files in the respective directories. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Shell (if always 4th line):

```
 for i in file*.txt; do cp $i "`sed -n 4p $i`/$i";done;
```

Comment: Thanks.. What if day is not always in 4th line?

Comment: Then you probably need a scan through the lot... Build an array of days, read line by line if any line matches any day, and move then. Is it always in english?